# Regression with libsvm: why the generated model contains lot of rows and not just one row

Tags: model, regression, libsvm, training-data

I'm using libsvm (a library to solve regression problems) to generate a model from a training set.

The generated model contains a lot of rows, but i expect that it contains just one row that represents the entire generated model. I think that each row corrisponds to one model.

For example: if i use as training set the data about one user, let's say 10 rows about user, then i expect that in generated model there is one row that represents the model of this user. But it isn't so.

Why? Or how should i interpret mean of generated rows?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data are you using - Is it sparse or dense? LibSVM [performs quite poor on regression](http://indiji.com/svm-vs-nn.html) compared to neural networks ([Nen Beta](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nen/)) - if you're interested in a linear model, you will have to convert the support vectors that make up the LibSVM-Model to a single weight-vector (plus bias) to make it interpretable.